# NSKeyedArchiver can archive an object in my array but not the array itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, persistence, protocols

```
var items = [CustomProtocol]()
... // add an item to items
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items, ...)
```

Fails to compile with

> Argument type '[CustomProtocol]' does not conform to expected type
>   AnyObject'

But if instead, I do like this:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(items[0], ...)
```

Everything works.

Comment: You have to check the concepts Deep copy and Shalow copy. Then select the one which best adapt to your needs,

Comment: I'm familiar with deep copying and shallow copying in general, but am unsure why it applies to the odd behavior of NSKeyedArchiver.